# Half-circle graphviz nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is it possible to have graphviz/dot render a node as a circle that is split in the middle horizontally, with a top and bottom text content? Something like a record, but the final shape should be a circle. Currently I'm using [Mrecord](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record), but that's only a rounded rectangle, not a circle shape.

I searched for ways to increase the border radius of Mrecord (to make it a quasi-circle) but that did not work. I also tried [Mcircle](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#d:Mcircle), which is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can create an image (svg, png, ...) that looks exactly like you want, using any drawing program, & then [include](https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqCustShape) that image in your Graphviz graph.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can create a [circle-shaped node](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#polygon), divided in half with the [`wedged`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/) attribute and in the [HTML-like `label`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) write a HTML `<TABLE>` without borders which will place text on top of the node.

Script:

```
digraph {
  nodepie  [shape = "circle"
            style = "wedged"
            fillcolor="white;0.5:white"
            label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0"> 
              <TR>
                <TD>one</TD>
              </TR> 
              <TR>
                <TD>two</TD>
              </TR> 
            </TABLE>>];
}
```

Result:
[image: node as circle that is split in middle horizontally, with top and bottom text content, made with GraphViz]